# How to filter launch time date in amazon ec2 using java?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Below is my code for the same.I'm trying to fetch instance ids which were launched 30 days before the current date. I'm unable to fetch data as it returns an empty list.

```
public List<String> getFilteredInstances(){
        List<String> instanceIds=getAllInstanceIds();
        Filter instanceIdFilter = new Filter("instance-id",instanceIds);
        //Creating date
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        List<String> launchTimeFilterValue = new ArrayList<>();
        //Subtracting 30 days from the current date
        launchTimeFilterValue.add(today.minusDays(30).toString());
        Filter launchTimeFilter = new Filter("launch-time",launchTimeFilterValue);
        AmazonEC2 amazonEC2 = AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.defaultClient();
        DescribeInstancesRequest request = new DescribeInstancesRequest();
        DescribeInstancesResult response = amazonEC2.describeInstances(request.withFilters(instanceIdFilter, launchTimeFilter));

        List<String> filteredInstanceIds=new ArrayList<>();
           response.getReservations().stream()
               .flatMap(reservation -> reservation.getInstances().stream())
               .forEach(instance -> filteredInstanceIds.add(instance.getInstanceId()));

        return filteredInstanceIds;}
```

Comment: Can you share the `response` object. While doing that, maybe you can also share if the list is still empty when you apply no filters to describe i.e. `DescribeInstancesResult response = amazonEC2.describeInstances(new DescribeInstancesRequest());`

Comment: Hi I was able to retrieve without the filters but no luck with filter. As a last resort I filtered the list for the launch-time.  .filter(instance -> instance.getLaunchTime().before(today.minusDays(30).toDate()))